# android Fragment/gesture detection ,up and down

Tags: android, android-fragments, gesture

i have a fragment class available , where on flinging up need to call fragment x and flinging down call fragment y, checked multiple solutions dint work please provide code .

```
public class Image_1 extends Fragment   {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image1_activity, container, false);
/////fling up 
///--->fragment x 
/////fling down
///--->fragment y 
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do it with GestureDetector, have you tried it?

Comment: It should work, you only need to know if the fling was up or down, what have you tried in onFling?

Comment: public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"down",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Test", "On Fling");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"fling",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

Comment: for checking i gave a toast message , dint come up

Comment: Are you calling the gesturedetector.onTouchEvent() passing the motion event? try onInterceptTouchEvent(motionevent){ gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(motionevent);}